# How to return the biggest distance between any two letters (a-z ignoring case)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to return a function which takes a string as input and returns the biggest distance between any two letters (a-z ignoring case). Distance in this case means the number of letters apart in the alphabet. E.g Distance between "a" and "b" is 1. Should I be using `string.index` or `chr` and `ord`?

My code so far:

```
def biggest_letter_distance(string):
    dist = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
    return dist
```

What I'm trying to test on:

```
assert(biggest_letter_distance("Hello World") == 19)
assert(biggest_letter_distance("!!") == -1)
```

Comment: You could look for the `min` and `max` letter first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def biggest_letter_distance(string):
    string = [char.lower() for char in string if char.isalpha()]
    if not string:
        return -1
    letters = sorted(set(string))
    return ord(letters[-1]) - ord(letters[0])
```

Explaining:

1. Selects only the alphabetic characters and turns them to lowercase.
2. Orders the selection
3. Returns the distance between the first and last items

Comment: or without sorting `ord(max(string)) - ord(min(string))`

Comment: Yes! Just don't forget to remove the non-alpha characters and to turn all to lower/upper.

Comment: Instead of converting to a `set`, you can change the first line to a set-comp instead of list-comp (just change `[]` to `{}`)